# UBUNTU 17.04" Failed to start Android emulator in Android Studio

Tags: 14.04, android, bug-reporting, android-studio, emulation

[Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IyAP.png)

I tried the solution i found which installing lib64stdc++6 AND mesa-utils
and installed successfully but when i do the next command:
cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++
it says No such a file or directory

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? Develop android apps ? Play games ? . FWIW , IMHO, the android emulators are sketchy in Linux, but it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: am developing an android application using android studio , but i can't debug the application because when i start the emulator it keeps showing me punch of errors that shown in the image bellow

Comment: I understand, however, I am not sure how much support you will have here for debugging android apps you write as this is not really directly related to Ubuntu. I would answer if I  could, see https://developer.android.com/support.html